# Exceeded sample count in FrameTime Google map flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, google-maps

My log is flooded by this message: Exceeded sample count in Frame Time, especially when using real device (Samsung s9 w/android 10), and rendering google maps.
Exceeded sample count in Frame Time

[image]

Comment: I meet this problem 2，has you got any answer yet ?